# How to add custom headers on swashbuckl asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I created a webapi on asp.net core and for the documentation I am using swagger swashbuckl.

My API need's some custom headers to validate request along with jwt-token

I need this custom headers

orgid: fe5mp0
brnid: NY0023
Authorization: Bearer

I managed to add Authorization header and it is working but can't find how to add these custom headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official explanation is here

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/501#issuecomment-143254123

```
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "Foo-Header",
                @in = "header",
                type = "string",
                required = true
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: And you should uncomment `c.OperationFilter<AddSwagerRequiredHeaderParameter>();` line on `SwaggerConfig.cs` class.